# Unable to split content into multiple flowfiles from ExecuteScript's flowfile

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a test flow to split the dates into multiple flowfile. These dates are generated from ExecuteScript.

But unfortunately while using `SplitContent` to split into multiple flowfiles, the flowfile attributes remain same and not splitted.

Following is my flow:

[image]

The ExecuteScript produces flowfile attribute `all_first_dates` as follows:
[image]

I use this in my UpdateAttribute to assign all_first_dates to `dates` attribute.
[image]

And as my dates values are delimited as newline, I gave configuration for splitcontent as follows:

[image]

But on splitting, I find the result remains same as original.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SplitContent** processor **splits flowfile contents** based on the `byte sequence` but `not the flowfile attributes`.

In your case **flow** will be something like below:

```
1.GenerateFlowfile
2.ExecuteScript
3.ReplaceText //Always replace as Replacement strategy and 
    Replacement value as ${all_first_dates}
4.SplitContent (or) SplitText //to split each line as individual flowfile
5.ExtractText //add new property dates with value as (.*)
    Now each flowfile will have dates attribute with the value
6.PutFile.
```

In addition if you want to get some specific value from ${all_first_dates} then use [getDelimitedField](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#getdelimitedfield) function on the attribute value using `UpdateAttribute` processor.